# Как выровнять элементы в выпадающем списке (select)

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5

Появилась небольшая проблема с тегом select.Дело в том, что нужно выровнять по центру элементы в теге select вот таким образом :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я это сделал с помощью padding-left.
Проблема в том, что при клике на select, padding появляется у всех элементов списка и выглядит это печально:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать выравнивание таким образом, чтобы выбранный элемент находился всегда по центру, а элементы в выпадающем списке выравнивались по левому краю?Как-то вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: приведите пример кода

Answer (score 0, accepted):

может так, у меня вроде как работает. Если у вас нет, укажите под какой браузер задача.

```css
select {
 width: 100px;
 text-align: center;
 text-align-last: center;
}
option {
 text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<select name="select_number">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
   <option value="5">5</option>
   <option value="6">6</option>
   <option value="7">7</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Safari не поддерживает text-align-last совсем: https://caniuse.com/#search=text-align-last Не знаю, насколько для автора вопроса важна поддержка маковского браузера

Answer (score 2):

Нативную конструкцию select option штатными средствами css стилизовать нельзя. Вы можете поискать какие-нибудь готовые плагины либо сами написать что-то такое:

```js
$('.option').mouseover(function(){
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $('.option').not(this).removeClass('active');
});

$('.select').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('open');
})

$('.option').click(function(){
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $('.option').not(this).removeClass('active');
  $('.output').text($(this).text());
})
```

```css
.select {
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.select.open {
  height: auto;
}
.select:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  border: 8px solid transparent;
  border-top: 12px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}
.output, .option {
  cursor: default;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.output {
  text-align: center;
}
.option.active {
  background-color: #1390ff;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="select">
  <div class="output">Генеральная уборка</div>
  <div class="option active">Генеральная уборка</div>
  <div class="option">Уборка после ремонта</div>
  <div class="option">Мойка окон, витрин магазинов</div>
  <div class="option">Мойка фасадов, витрин зданий</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Действительно, оказалось намного проще подключить плагин selectize.js и не париться.